# Why "ftp_fget" is returning "bind() failed: Permission denied (13)" in php?

Tags: php, ftp, permission-denied

I'm trying to read a csv file on a distant server using the `ftp_fget` and `fgetcsv` functions. I already practice this multiple times when reading files on distant servers and until now it works fine.

I can't figure out why ftp_fget is returning this error: `bind() failed: Permission denied (13)`.
Furthermore, I can't find any real explanations about this error message too.

My client who gave me distant server access said it's a *Windows Server*.

```
$distant_folder = "/myfolder/";
$filename = "myfile.csv";

$ftpstream = ftp_connect($ftp_server); 
$login = ftp_login($ftpstream, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass);

if($login){
    $tmp_handle = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');

    if (ftp_fget($ftpstream, $tmp_handle, $distant_folder.$filename, FTP_ASCII)){
        // do stuff with fgetcsv()...
    }
}
```

*Please notice values of the ftp server variables are hidden for confidential reasons.*

**EDIT : I found a solution!**

I used `ftp_pasv($ftpstream, true);` between `ftplogin()` and `ftp_fget()` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to switch the connection to passive mode, so your FTP client ask a port to connect to the FTP server. Put it before ftp_put(), ftp_get(), ftp_nlist(), etc. for example:

```
ftp_pasv($connId, true);
$list = ftp_nlist($connId, ".");
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. My script for copy the file is:

```
<?php
//Show erros:
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// connect and login to FTP server
$ftp_server = "ftp.painelx.com";
$ftp_conn   = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server.<br>");
$login      = ftp_login($ftp_conn, 'user_ftp', 'pass_ftp') or die("Could not login to $ftp_server.<br>");

$local_file = "data.xml";
$server_file = "/paineis/wg/dataxml/data.xml";

//Directory and file(/paineis/wg/dataxml/data.xml) on remote server(ftp.painelx.com)
/*
```

[image]

```
*/

if($login) {
    echo "Connected to painel.";

    ftp_pasv($ftp_conn, true); // ! IMPORTANT

    $permission = ftp_get($ftp_conn, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_ASCII);

    if ($permission) {
        echo "Successfully written to $local_file.<br>";
    } else {
        echo "Error downloading $server_file.<br>";
    }

} else {
    echo "NOT connected.<br>";
}

ftp_close($ftp_conn);
?>
```

PS.: This same problem appeared on www.ipage.com host.

Comment: NOTE: Script with SOLVED PROBLEM